Different outcomes when listing Authorized Views from UI versus Command line
I am getting different outcomes when I try listing Authorized Views from the UI as compared to when I list them from the Command line.
Steps to list Authorized Views through UI are:

Access the dataset: In the BigQuery console, locate the dataset where the view resides.
Open dataset details: Click on the dataset name to access its properties.
Check sharing settings: Look for the "Sharing" option and select it.
Verify authorized views list: Within the sharing settings, you will see a list of authorized views for that dataset; if your view is listed, it is an authorized view

Steps to list Authorized Views through command line:

Access CloudShell from GCP console in your Browser
Execute command ”bq show --dataset=true {your_dataset_name}”

I am expecting that the above 2 approaches give me the exact same outcome but they are not. The latter shows views which are not otherwise displayed using the former
